# Error ORA-01034: ORACLE not available and ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist when trying to log in as system

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am completely new at SQL plus. I forgot what I did during the class but now I want to try again by watching back the videos. I cannot login as system even after I changed the password by logging in using conn /as sysdba and alter user system identified by password;

what should I do?
[image]

*Update*
I also made sure that the services are up. It's already up when I asked this question.
[image]

Comment: Looks like your database isn't up. So - start it.

Comment: How do I start it?

Comment: In order to do IPC (inter process comm) aka "sqlplus / as sysdba" you need to point sqlplus to the correct memory+process (instance). This is done by exporting the environment. on linux you do:  .  oraenv (you will be asked for instance name). On windows you do set ORACLE_SID=<my_sid>

Comment: like this?
Enter user-name: ORACLE_SID=<my_sid> 
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]

Comment: In your shell: C:\>set ORACLE_SID=XE, next C:\>sqlplus "/ as sysdba". Note! 'XE' is a guess, you need to find this value. Look at the oracle processes on your machine or Oracle Windows Services. At last SQL>startup

Comment: Aha! Do not klick on the sqlplus icon and input anything. Use the CLI version of sqlplus. First fire up a cmd.exe thereafter set environment, next sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

Comment: To start a local database on Windows: Open services (services.msc), look for services OracleDatabase... and OracleService... . Start them if down. Start also the listener service. Since you get "realm does not exist" I think the service is up, the database not.

Comment: @Tuxinose I checked OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent and OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener and both are running, I even restarted both of them and started the rest of the oracle services. Problem still not solved

Comment: So: cmd.exe -> C:\>set ORACLE_SID=ORCL -> C:\>sqlplus "/ as sysdba" -> SQL>startup. Please post the output to your question.

Comment: If that does not work you are not in the right OS group. But if you know the system password you should be able to connect: system/password@ORCL